# corona virus vaccine side effects

Tags: covid-19, side-effects, coronavirus

First I like to mention that I have no medical background

I have read that there are 2 types of vaccines for the corona virus currently developed

- A RNA based vaccine, which is based on a novel ~untested approach
- A adenovirus vaccine, which has bean used for many years for other vaccines

The adenovirus vaccine is basically a modified adenovirus, which is used to deliver the code (RNA?) for a corona specific protein to the cell, which is then mass produced   and forces the immune system to recognize this specific protein.

This raises the following questions:

1. Did I understand everything correctly ?
2. Does the adenovirus kill the infected  cell ?
3. The corona vaccine will be just another adenovirus based vaccine, which only differs in the payload. So the only side effects caused by the vaccine can be the same as for all other adenovirus vaccines ( provided the payload is safe). If so  is there a another reason besides the certification standards that the testing takes so long ?
4. How do you modify something so small as a virus and then force it to multiply in a egg ?
5. What are other chemical components contained in a vaccine and how do they keep the virus "alive"?
6. How does the RNA vaccine force the cell to produce the protein ?
7. Is the coronavirus protein the red part on the image bellow (ie the ~connector used to enter the cell? )

[image]

Comment: I don't think this question can be answered because the only coronavirus vaccine that has been released for public use at this point is one the Russians claim to have developed, which the rest of the world is very skeptical of. When a vaccine is finally approved in the west, you can try re-asking this question, but please keep it limited to _one question_, not seven.